# Angular: display content projection with nested children

Tags: angular, viewchild, angular-content-projection

I have a component where I would like to display configurable html in the child component. Child components are not accessible to the client. So I think what I'm looking for is [content projection](https://angular.io/guide/content-projection)

```
<Parent>
 <ng-template #editTemplate> //custom 
   <button>Edit Me </button>
 </ng-template>    
 <child1>
     ...
     <child4>
       I would like to show the #editTemplate here
     </child4>
 </child1>
</Parent>
```

so Inside of `child4`

I have this HTML

```
<div>
  <ng-content #editTemplate></ng-content>
</div>
```

However I can't get the button to display. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have here is an interesting combination of content projection and dependency injection.

`<ng-template #editTemplate>` is being content-projected into `Parent` component

```html
<Parent>
 <ng-template #editTemplate> <--- projected into <Parent>
   <button>Edit Me </button>
 </ng-template>
</Parent>
```

so `Parent` has a direct reference to it via [Content Child](https://angular.io/api/core/ContentChild), if your `Parent` component looks something like this:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'parent',
  template: `
  <h2>Parent here!</h2>

  <ng-content></ng-content> <--- #editTemplate will get projected here

  <child1></child1>
  `,
  styles: [`h1 { font-family: Lato; }`],
})
export class ParentComponent {
  @ContentChild('editTemplate') editTemplate: TemplateRef<any>; // <--- reference to #editTemplate
}
```

However, `child4` is nested several layers deep, so dependency injection is your friend here, otherwise you would need to configure a reference *in each layer* to complete the chain from `Parent` down to `child4`.

Using DI, though, you can inject the `Parent` component directly into `child4`, who can then access the `editTemplate` reference on the `Parent` component instance and use [*ngTemplateOutlet](https://angular.io/api/common/NgTemplateOutlet) to insert the view from that `TemplateRef`.

So `child4` could look like this:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'child4',
  template: `
  <h3>Child 4 here!</h3>
  <div>And here's the injected template:</div>

  <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="projectedTemplate"></ng-container> <--- use *ngTemplateOutlet to render editTemplate
  `,
  styles: [`h1 { font-family: Lato; }`],
})
export class Child4Component {
  projectedTemplate: TemplateRef<any>;

  constructor(private parentComponent: ParentComponent) {} // <-- inject ParentComponent instance

  ngOnInit() {
    this.projectedTemplate = this.parentComponent.editTemplate; // <-- set *ngTemplateOutlet to editTemplate
  }
}
```

[Here's a StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-vz1bv8?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fparent.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fchild4.component.ts) showing this approach.

Comment: Thanks for the solution, The DI was the piece I was missing. I didn't even think of injecting the parent inside of the child component. I was hoping the `ContentChild` could have somehow been used in the child component. This solution works very well!

Comment: @Train, content projected into `child4` would need to be defined within the `<child4>` tags rather than the `<Parent>` tags. If, however, `<child4>` is in the same template as `#editTemplate` as shown in your html snippet (I assumed that was just to summarize your scenario, and that `child4` actually lives in `child3`'s template, `child3` lives in `child2`'s template, etc.), you could create an `Input` on `child4` and pass a reference to `#editTemplate` into it directly instead of using DI: `<child4 [tmpl]="editTemplate"></child4>`.

Comment: Thanks, your assumption was correct child 4 lives in child 3 and so on.